# Display <textarea> on each content that is being generated dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have questions and options (multiple choice questions) listed on a page generated dynamically. I want to give this to content management team where if they find any error in question they can click on 'Note' and a text area opens up for that question and they can write that note. So now if I am clicking on one question the textarea opens, but if I click on the next question's 'Note' option, the text area opens on the earlier question's part. How this can be rectified, I have looked around but no clues.Let me know where I am going wrong.

```
<?php if($row['section'] == 1) {?>  
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item active">
<div class="radio noMargin" id="<?php echo $sectionOne ; ?>info"><?php echo $no ; ?> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></div><?php echo "<font color='pink'>Ques ID :[".$row['id']."]</font>";?><div class="question"><?php echo $row['question'] ; ?></div>
<div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;">
 <div onclick= "myFunction()"> <font color='yellow'>Notes</font></div>  


Marks:<?php echo $row['marks'] ; ?></div></li>
<?php          
echo '<input type="hidden" name="question[]" id="questionId" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="attempt" value="'.$attemptCount.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="unit_id" value="'.$unit_id.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="chapter_id" value="'.$chapter_id.'">';

$questionId     =   $row['id'] ;  

$sqO =$db->query("SELECT id, options from  tbl_options_mock_question WHERE question_id = ".$questionId."");
while($rowO=mysql_fetch_array($sqO))
{
?>  
    <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
      <div class="radio noMargin">
        <label>
          <input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="<?php echo $no ; ?>"  name="optionAns<?php echo $i ; ?>"  value="<?php echo $rowO['id'] ; ?>">
          <?php echo $rowO['options'] ; ?></label>
      </div>
    </li>

<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<div class='comment_form'><form action='#' method='post'><textarea class='span10' name='Comment' rows='6'></textarea><br><input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Reply'></form></div>";
}  
</script>

</ul>
<div id="demo"></div>         
<?php $i++;$no++; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hard to tell with all the php hieroglyphs and using `innerHTML=` instead of just adding the html to the page and show/hiding it - but it looks like your `<div id=demo` code resides *inside* a loop - therefore you will have multiple divs with the same id - when you then try to find one by id it will only get the first one.

Comment: Also the += will clear any content of the previous textarea when added because the code does NOT copy the content of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery tag is added there so i will give a jquery solution:-

1.convert `<div id="demo"></div>` to `<div class="demo"></div>` and put it inside `<ul></ul>`

2.remove `onclick` from div and add class `click_notes` on that div

3.Add jquery library and use below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.click_notes').on('click',function(){
   $('.comment_form').hide(); //hide show form
   $(this).closest('ul').find('.demo').html("<div class='comment_form'><form action='#' method='post'><textarea class='span10' name='Comment' rows='6'></textarea><br><input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Reply'></form></div>");
 });
});
```

Sample snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.click_notes').on('click',function(){
   $('.comment_form').hide();//hide show form
   $(this).closest('ul').find('.demo').html("<div class='comment_form'><form action='#' method='post'><textarea class='span10' name='Comment' rows='6'></textarea><br><input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Reply'></form></div>");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">Ques ID :1<div class="question">Q1</div><div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;"><div class="click_notes"> <font color='yellow'>Notes</font></div>Marks:5</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin"><label><input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="1"  name="optionAns1"  value="1">1</label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin"><label><input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="2"  name="optionAns2"  value="1">2</label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin"><label><input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="3"  name="optionAns3"  value="1">3</label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin"><label><input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="4"  name="optionAns4"  value="1">4</label></div>
  </li>
  <div class="demo"></div>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">Ques ID :2<div class="question">Q2</div><div style="float:right; margin-top:-20px;"><div class="click_notes"> <font color='yellow'>Notes</font></div>Marks:5</div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin"><label><input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="1"  name="optionAns1"  value="1">1</label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin"><label><input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="2"  name="optionAns2"  value="1">2</label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin"><label><input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="3"  name="optionAns3"  value="1">3</label></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item wrp_radio">
    <div class="radio noMargin"><label><input disabled type="radio" class="checkedInfo" alt="4"  name="optionAns4"  value="1">4</label></div>
  </li>
  <div class="demo"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This is what I wanted. Its working as I wanted it to be. Thanks alot . Keep up the good work.

Comment: Yes and one last thing, can this text area be toggled for hide and show ??

Comment: @Ansh  yes, i have added code for that too. check in my answer

Comment: I tried this. ` $('.comment_form').hide();` this part. But unfortunately not working

Comment: Even for the code snippet trial above , its not working on that too. Something else can be done??

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
<div id="demo"></div>         
<?php $i++;$no++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

will create multiple divs with `id=demo` so when you use `document.getElementById("demo")` it only gets the first.

Use a class instead of an id and then use relative navigation to get the relevant one.

Keeping the `onclick=` and using jquery (as per the tags) this would become:

```
<div onclick= "myFunction(this)">

function myFunction(el) {
    $(el).closest(".list-group-item").find(".demo").html("<div class='comment_form...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have question on this.`function myFunction(el) {
    $(el).closest(".list-group-item").find(".demo").html` .... What will be the value of `el`

Comment: `el` will be the value of `this` passed in from the `onclick` `<div onclick= "myFunction(this)">`

Comment: When using jquery you would normally wire up the event separate from the markup, so would not need it as `this` would already be defined.  As your question was tagged jquery but didn't actually have any jquery I kept the changes to a minimum.